# Type.GetType Failing but property.PropertyType Works Fine

Tags: c#

I am iterating through the object and initializing all the properties of that object. First the type of the object i.e class was placed in my same project and it worked fine. Now, I moved the class into a different project but still making the same object by using AssemblyName.Namespace.Class but it stopped working.

Here is my previous code:

```
var o = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(property.PropertyType.Name));
```

The above always returned null. So, I tried the following:

```
var o = Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType);
```

and it worked and created the correct object. I am curious why this happened!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Type.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) requires the *full* name of the type, including assembly information, unless the type is in the same assembly as the caller or mscorlib. Additionally, you need to make sure you've got the namespace as well. So `Type.FullName` should work within the same assembly or mscorlib, and `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName` should always work.

But hey, if you already have the type as a `Type` from the `PropertyType` property, there's no point in calling `Type.GetType` anyway :)

Comment: Thanks Jon! You are right! I already have PropertyType so no need to call Type.GetType :)